# Can't find the error: Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I'm trying to write a registration page for clients but this error appears in every moment.

Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

I've followed this tutorial: http://untame.net/2013/06/how-to-build-a-functional-login-form-with-php-twitter-bootstrap/
The DB is this:
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjyAc.png)

The code is this:

```
    <?php


        require("config.php");
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    }
    require("config.php");

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 

        // Ensure that the user fills out fields 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { die("Please enter a username."); } 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { die("Please enter a password."); } 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); } 

        // Check if the username is already taken
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
        $query_params = array( ':nombre' => $_POST['nombre'] );
        $query_params = array( ':empresa' => $_POST['empresa'] );
        $query_params = array( ':apellidos' => $_POST['apellidos'] );

        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ die("This username is already in use"); } 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 
        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 


        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ die("This email address is already registered"); } 

        // Add row to database 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                empresa,
                nombre,
                apellidos

            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email,
                :empresa,
                :nombre,
                :apellidos
            )"; 
        /*      



        */

        // Security measures
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){ $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); } 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'], 
            ':empresa' => $_POST['empresa'],
            ':nombre' => $_POST['nombre'],
            ':apellidos' => $_POST['apellidos']
        ); 
        try {  
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        header("Location: index.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
    } 
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Tutorial</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap Tab + Fixed Sidebar Tutorial with HTML5 / CSS3 / JavaScript">
    <meta name="author" content="Untame.net">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <style type="text/css">
        body { background: url(assets/bglight.png); }
        .hero-unit { background-color: #fff; }
        .center { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand">Registro en 4tickets</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="index.php">Volver a casa</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container hero-unit">
    <h1>Register</h1> <br /><br />
    <form action="register.php" method="post"> 
        <label>Username:</label> 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
        <label>Email: <strong style="color:darkred;">*</strong></label> 
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 
        <label>Password:</label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> <br />
        <label>Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" /> <br />
        <label>apellidos:</label>
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" value="" /> <br />
        <label>Empresa:</label>
        <input type="text" name="empresa" value="" /> <br />
        <p style="color:darkred;">* Poner bien las direcciones de mail</p><br />
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Register" /> 
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I've seen that all the variables are ok and I don't know where is the error.

My config.php

```
<?php 

    // These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database 
    $username = "root"; 
    $password = "root"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "4tickets"; 

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
    try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
    session_start(); 
?>
```

I've only added 3 things: empresa, nombre and apellidos that weren't in the tutorial and I needed.

Thanks in advance,
John.

Comment: You're passing too many parameters into your first query. You only have :username in your query, but you're passing in 3 others as well.

Comment: how could I do it?

Comment: $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'], array( ':nombre' => $_POST['nombre'] , ':empresa' => $_POST['empresa'], ':apellidos' => $_POST['apellidos']  ); 

For example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing in the wrong parameters here:

```
    // Check if the username is already taken
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
    $query_params = array( ':nombre' => $_POST['nombre'] );
    $query_params = array( ':empresa' => $_POST['empresa'] );
    $query_params = array( ':apellidos' => $_POST['apellidos'] );
```

You're attempting to pass in too many parameters, but you're also overwriting `$query_params` each time. Take out the hombre, empress, and apellidos in this section, and it should submit.